# Python and manipulation of list

Tags: python

I have a list something like below.

- com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd: 3 times, 28945 ms
- com.whatsapp: 24 times, 1800631 ms
- com.android.vending: 3 times, 305155 ms

What I am looking for is simple way of formatting this in a table and sorting this list based either upon the 'no of times' or 'duration'

Note: I have tried 'tabulate' package but didn't give me proper results.

Comment: What is the expected output, what did you try, why didn't it work, and what was the actual output?

Comment: 1. Sort the above list to have 24 times as the first item in the list 2. I would like to display it in a table format  Package    Times     Duration  3. I didn't get the expected formatting results through tabulate

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you must use is [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), So you can represent the data as :

```
data = {"com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd": [3, 28945],
        "com.whatsapp"            : [24, 1800631],
        "com.android.vending"     : [3, 305155]   }

package_name = data.keys()

package_name.sort(key = lambda x:data[x][0])  #sorting this list based upon the 'no of times'

package_name.sort(key = lambda x:data[x][1])  #sorting this list based upon the 'duration'
```

**Output:**

```
['com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd', 'com.android.vending', 'com.whatsapp']
#sorting this list based upon the 'no of times'

['com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd', 'com.android.vending', 'com.whatsapp']
#sorting this list based upon the 'duration'
```